# Chrome autofill should set the form to valid

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vue.js

On the first image, you see a bug, where Chrome does not set the form to valid when autofilling.

[image]

This is how it should look like.

[image]

I found a Github Issue to my issue [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3414), but it is based on Angular. I'm working with Vue.

The label goes only up when the field is focues or valid.

```
input:focus ~ label, input:valid ~ label        {
  top:-20px;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#5264AE;
}
```

Besides that, the html with shadow nodes looks like this:

```
<input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="username" data-vv-delay="500" aria-label="Your email" required="required" class="" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
   <div pseudo="-internal-input-suggested" id="placeholder" style="display: block !important;">avidofood@somemail.com</div>
</input>
```

What could I do?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found one solution over [here](https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/pull/1868).

In my case it's (input:-webkit-autofil):

```
input:focus ~ label, input:valid ~ label, input:-webkit-autofill ~ label{
  top:-20px;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#5264AE;
}
```